# Find islands using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to find islands (type not water, completely surrounded by water) in a polygon table. The polygons are not overlapping.

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE islands (
   ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
   type VARCHAR (10),
   geom geometry);
INSERT INTO islands(type, geom)
   VALUES
   ('water',st_geomfromewkt('SRID=3006;POLYGON((510796 6429408,513939 6420063,526040 6421096,527763 6430183,517341 6436643,510796 6429408),(516954 6429623,516652 6425747,518203 6426436,519667 6428073,516954 6429623))')),
   ('land',st_geomfromewkt('SRID=3006;POLYGON((516954 6429623,516652 6425747,518203 6426436,519667 6428073,516954 6429623))')),
   ('land',st_geomfromewkt('SRID=3006;POLYGON((510796 6429408,517341 6436643,512561 6436427,508384 6434619,510796 6429408),(511011 6434231,512475 6435652,513207 6433025,511011 6434231))')),
   ('land',st_geomfromewkt('SRID=3006;POLYGON((511011 6434231,512475 6435652,513207 6433025,511011 6434231))'));
```

Only id 2 should be selected:
[image]

I have tried query below based on [Determine if a polygon is not enclosed by other polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/determine-if-a-polygon-is-not-enclosed-by-other-polygons), but it is not selecting anything.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM islands a 
INNER JOIN islands b ON (ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id != b.id)
where a.type = 'water' and b.type <> 'water'
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING 1e-6 > 
  abs(ST_Length(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom)) - 
  sum(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(ST_Exteriorring(a.geom), st_interiorringn(b.geom,1)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have **a guaranteed topological equality** between island and water polygon rings, using a simpler `EXISTS` filter should increase performance:

```
SELECT  a.id
FROM    islands AS a
WHERE   a.type <> 'water'
  AND   EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    islands AS b,
            LATERAL ST_DumpRings(b.geom) AS dmp   -- rings to polygons
    WHERE   b.type = 'water'
      AND   dmp.path[1] > 0                       -- only interior rings
      AND   ST_Equals(a.geom, dmp.geom)
  )
;
```

- `ST_DumpRings` is relatively cheap compared to constructing geometries, and enables finding matches more generically for all inner rings of a water body polygon
- `EXISTS` will quit its execution once the first result row of its query is truthy
- no additional aggregation (`GROUP BY`) required

---

@Cyril's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350905/93656) will also work great with `ST_DumpPoints`, i.e. using

```
...
tblb AS (SELECT dmp.geom FROM islands, LATERAL ST_DumpRings(geom) AS dmp WHERE type = 'water' AND dmp.path[1] > 0)
...
```

---

If **topological equality is not guaranteed**, you could check for `ST_Within` on the exterior ring polygon:

```
SELECT  a.id
FROM    islands AS a
WHERE   a.type <> 'water'
  AND   EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    islands AS b,
            LATERAL ST_DumpRings(b.geom) AS dmp  -- rings to polygon
    WHERE   b.type = 'water'
      AND   dmp.path[1] = 0                      -- only exterior ring
      AND   ST_Within(a.geom, dmp.geom)
);
```

Comment: Nice! (My real data was multipolygons so I had to `st_dump` them into polygons first)

Comment: @BERA Cool! Btw. if you expect many inner rings to be checked, you can add `a.geom && b.geom` to the inner querys `WHERE` filter. This should give a little boost even without indexes (that are likely not being used after the dump to singletons).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to solve the question asked.

Run the script:

```
WITH                                                                          
tbla AS (SELECT * FROM islands WHERE type = 'land'),
tblb AS (SELECT ST_InteriorRingN(geom,1) geom FROM islands WHERE type = 'water')
SELECT ID, type, (a.geom) geom FROM tbla a INNER JOIN tblb b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Check the result, and if I misunderstood the question, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The query will work only for islands placed in the first interior ring of a water body, and for topological correct geometries. Your case fills both requeriments.

The only change is that you are referring as table `a` as if they were the land bodies, but you are filtering `a.type = 'water'`, and the opposite for the table `b`.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM islands a 
INNER JOIN islands b ON (ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id != b.id)
where a.type = 'land' and b.type <> 'land'
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING 1e-6 > 
  abs(ST_Length(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom)) - 
  sum(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(ST_Exteriorring(a.geom), st_interiorringn(b.geom,1)))));
```

Returns:

```
 id
----
  2
(1 row)
```